# PHP: поиск в одной колонке многомерного массива

Tags: php, массивы, поиск

Есть многомерный ассоциативный массив `$array`:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array ( [amount] => 100 [currency] => 643 )
  [1] => Array ( [amount] => 200 [currency] => 643 )
  [2] => Array ( [amount] => 300 [currency] => 643 )
  [3] => Array ( [amount] => 400 [currency] => 643 )
)
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как на PHP можно проверить, присутствует ли в этом массиве у ключа `amount` значение `100`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

взять колонку и поискать

```
$exists = (array_search(100, array_column($data, 'amount')) !== false);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но только ваша переменная $exists мне всегда возвращает 1, вне зависимости от того, какое значение я ищу

Comment: @Win_D а да, натупил, `>= 0` заменить на `!== false` следует.

Answer (score 1):

```
$exists = in_array(100, array_column($array, 'amount'));
```